# How to for loop using Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of strings that I want to iterate through a loop. However, I am not sure how to create a for loop for this task. The function scrapes information from a website. The tables have tens of thousands of rows depending on the "name". How can I do this?

I have list:

```
list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```

Here is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_results(search_term):
        global df
        url = "https://investor.dn.no/#!/NorgesAksjer/"       
        browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"))
        browser.get(url)
        search_box = browser.find_element_by_id("ar-search-input")
        search_box.send_keys(search_term)
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-lg.btn-primary").click()
        WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, search_term))).click()
        WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,  
                     "//*[@id='dninvestor-content']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a"))).click() # 
        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
                     "//*[@id='dninvestor-content']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[101]/td[1]/a"))).click() 
        time.sleep(5)
        result = []
        html = browser.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            for posts in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'col-xs-12 ng-scope'}):
                for tr in posts.findAll('tr')[1:]:
                    sh = [td for td in tr.stripped_strings]
                    result.append(list(sh))
                    df = pd.DataFrame(result)
        return result
```

I want to create a for loop such that `get_results(list)` would be:

```
get_results('name1')
get_results('name2')
get_results('name3')
```

and the results would be appened to `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like following:

```
final_result = []
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
for name in names:
    final_result.append(get_results(name))
```

What you do to convert to dataframe really depends on what structure you are building up.

If your function returned a list you could build up a list of lists in final_result then use pd.DataFrame to convert to dataframe.

Comment: Your solution looped through the list as I expected. However, the results were not stored to `final_result` as there were just `NoneType`s inside.

Comment: Did you add a return statement to your function that returned a list?

Comment: By simply adding `return result`? I just did, and nothing changed.

Comment: Put `return result` in the right location now. I got a list of a lists of strings. (In my example, three lists with lists consisting of strings). How do I convert this list of lists of strings to dataframe?

Comment: Use pd dataframe on results

Answer (score 1):

```
myListLen = len(list)
for i in range(0, myListLen):
  getResults(list[i])
```

Comment: This looped through the list, but the values were not stored.

Comment: You need to return the data from you function then code should be ->                                 
           new_Array = []                                                                                     
          then inside the loop                                               
          new_Array.append(get_results(name))